# How to import space-formatted tables (9.0)?

Tags: postgresql

This are the first three lines of my text file:

```
  Dist    Mv  CL Typ  LTef  logg Age Mass  B-V    U-B    V-I    V-K    V   [Fe/H] l           b         Av   Mbol
  0.033 14.40  5 7.90 3.481  5.10  1 0.15  1.723  1.512  3.153  5.850 17.008  0.13   0.50000   0.50000  0.014 12.616
  0.033  7.40  5 6.50 3.637  4.62  7 0.71  1.178  0.984  1.302  2.835 10.047 -0.56   0.50000   0.50000  0.014  6.125
  0.052 11.70  5 7.40 3.529  4.94  2 0.31  1.541  1.167  2.394  4.565 15.393 -0.10   0.50000   0.50000  0.028 10.075
```

Assuming I have the right columns, how do I import this?

Bonus: is it possible/are there tools to create the schema from these kinds of files automatically?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At lowest level you could just use [`COPY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-copy.html) command (or `\copy` in [`psql`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html) if you don't have access to superuser account, which `COPY` requires to load data from file). Unfortunately you have to create table structure at first (there is no built-in *guess-by-header* feature), but it looks straightforward to write one.

Choose whaterer suitable [datatype](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html) you need e.g. `real` for single precision floating-point (IEEE 754), `double precision` or `numeric` if you need arbitrary precision numbers:

```
CREATE TABLE measurement
(
    "Dist" double precision,
    "Mv" double precision,
    "CL" double precision,
    "Typ" double precision,
    "LTef" double precision,
    "logg" double precision,
    "Age" double precision,
    "Mass" double precision,
    "B-V" double precision,
    "U-B" double precision,
    "V-I" double precision,
    "V-K" double precision,
    "V" double precision,
    "[Fe/H]" double precision,
    "l" double precision,
    "b" double precision,
    "Av" double precision,
    "Mbol" double precision
);
```

Another thing is that your file contains multiple spaces between values, so it's better to transform it into **single-tab-delimited** entries (there are plenty of tools to do this):

```
$ sed 's/  */\t/g' import.csv
Dist    Mv  CL  Typ LTef    logg    Age Mass    B-V U-B V-I V-K V   [Fe/H]  l   b   Av  Mbol
0.033   14.40   5   7.90    3.481   5.10    1   0.15    1.723   1.512   3.153   5.850   17.008  0.13    0.50000 0.50000 0.014   12.616
0.033   7.40    5   6.50    3.637   4.62    7   0.71    1.178   0.984   1.302   2.835   10.047  -0.56   0.50000 0.50000 0.014   6.125
0.052   11.70   5   7.40    3.529   4.94    2   0.31    1.541   1.167   2.394   4.565   15.393  -0.10   0.50000 0.50000 0.028   10.075
```

Finally you can import your file straight into Postgres database, for example:

```
=> \copy measurement FROM '/path/import.csv' (FORMAT csv, DELIMITER E'\t', HEADER 'true')
=> TABLE measurement;
 Dist  |  Mv  | CL | Typ | LTef  | logg | Age | Mass |  B-V  |  U-B  |  V-I  |  V-K  |   V    | [Fe/H] |  l  |  b  |  Av   |  Mbol  
-------+------+----+-----+-------+------+-----+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+--------+-----+-----+-------+--------
 0.033 | 14.4 |  5 | 7.9 | 3.481 |  5.1 |   1 | 0.15 | 1.723 | 1.512 | 3.153 |  5.85 | 17.008 |   0.13 | 0.5 | 0.5 | 0.014 | 12.616
 0.033 |  7.4 |  5 | 6.5 | 3.637 | 4.62 |   7 | 0.71 | 1.178 | 0.984 | 1.302 | 2.835 | 10.047 |  -0.56 | 0.5 | 0.5 | 0.014 |  6.125
 0.052 | 11.7 |  5 | 7.4 | 3.529 | 4.94 |   2 | 0.31 | 1.541 | 1.167 | 2.394 | 4.565 | 15.393 |   -0.1 | 0.5 | 0.5 | 0.028 | 10.075
(3 rows)
```